# What options exist to quantitatively detect enzyme activity in non-model insect tissue?

Tags: biochemistry, entomology, enzymes

Evolution/genomics person here: what are the options to measure the activity or presence of broad categories of enzymes--like peroxidases or catalases--active in a specific tissue (in a non-model insect)?

I understand that antibodies, e.g. ELISA, may be one approach but am unsure if it's the best option or what the alternatives would be. Are any sequence based-approaches available, if I know the peptide sequence (or at least a specific function domain, ie Pfam ID)?

Comment: "I understand…". I don't think so. Antibodies are specific to one protein (you hope). They cannot be raised against a "broad category of enzymes". I think your question requires a little more thought.